# I don't get return string form restcontroller to jsp page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

```
 @Controller
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite");
        return "welcome";
    }
}


    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Greeting : ${greeting}
    This is a welcome page.
</body>
</html>
```

when a run the porgam get output "Greeting : ${greeting} This is a welcome page."

not get ${greeting} value on jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try to put following on top of the jsp page to enable expression language.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web.xml` file `web-app` tag , this tag is like `<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"............version="3.0">` , here version of servlet is `3.0` , JSP Expression Language[`{..}`] by default enabled in above 2.4 Servlet Version.

Servlet Version 2.3 [`<web-app xmlns:xsi=….. version=”2.3”>`] or lower Expression Language is not enabled by default.

**Activate EL For Single JSP:**
if you want to enable Expression Language in your JSP Pages just Use 
`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"isELIgnored="false" %>`

Simply : `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` or`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"isELIgnored="false" %>`

**Activate EL for all JSP Pages:**
 Activating EL(Expression Language) for all JSP Pages, just add below code to `web.xml` :

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
</jsp-property-group>
```

**Deactivating EL for Single JSP:**
If you want to Disable EL(expression Language) in JSP Pages Just Use Like
`<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>` or`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"isELIgnored="true" %>`

**Deactivating EL for all JSP Pages:** Deactivating EL(Expression Language) for all JSP Pages, just add below code to `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
</jsp-property-group>
```

if it helps please promote.